# Computation of mean and variance of $T$ with $P(T>t)$ given

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let's say we have:
$$
P(T>t) = ae^{-L t} + (1-a) e^{-ut},
$$ 
where $T$ is the duration, $t \geq 0$; and $0 \leq a \leq 1$, $L > 0$, $u > 0$ are constants.

What's here, in this case, the mean and the variance of $T$?

@Stefan: Your first comment is: "If you differentiate the cumulative distribution function $F(t)=P(T≤t)$ , then you obtain the density of T [...]". 
My question: Why is this correct? I mean, why $F(t)=P(T≤t)$ and not $F(t)=P(T>t)$ ?

Comment: If you differentiate the cumulative distribution function $F(t)=P(T\leq t)$, then you obtain the density of $T$ which enables you to compute the mean and variance.

Comment: Please use LaTeX commands for the mathematical expressions.

Comment: @Stefan What if there is no density?

Comment: @Did: Isn't a sufficient condition for the density to exist that the CDF is continuous differentiable?

Comment: @Stefan, As you know, it is. But it is not necessary to rely on PDF since a quite general procedure exists, valid for **every** distribution.

Comment: @Did: Point taken.

Answer (score 3):

If $T\geqslant0$ almost surely, then
$$
T=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathbf 1_{T\gt t}\,\mathrm dt
\quad\implies\quad
\mathbb E(T)=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathbb P(T\gt t)\,\mathrm dt.
$$
Likewise,
$$
T^2=\int_0^{+\infty}2t\,\mathbf 1_{T\gt t}\,\mathrm dt
\quad\implies\quad
\mathbb E(T^2)=\int_0^{+\infty}2t\,\mathbb P(T\gt t)\,\mathrm dt.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(t) := \mathbb{P}(T \leq t)$ the cumulative distribution function. If $f$ is differentiable, the fundamental theorem of calculus implies $$\mathbb{P}[T \leq t] = f(t) = \int_0^t f'(x) \, dx$$ where we used $f(0)=0$ since $T \geq 0$. This shows that the distribution $\mathbb{P}_T$ of $T$ has density $1_{[0,\infty)}(x) \cdot f'(x)$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Thus $$\mathbb{E}T = \int_{[0,\infty)} x \cdot f'(x) \, dx \qquad \qquad \text{var} \, \, T = \int_{[0,\infty)} (x-\mathbb{E}T)^2 \cdot f'(x) \, dx \tag{1}$$ (if the integrals are finite).

So you have to calculate the derivative of $f$, i.e. $$f'(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \big(a \cdot e^{-L \cdot t}+(1-a) \cdot e^{-u \cdot t} \big)$$ and compute the integrals in $(1)$.

Comment: What if there is no density?

Comment: @Did In this case, there is. But I see your point.